# Flutter Change height of an OutlineButton inside an AppBar?

Tags: button, height, flutter

Just wondering how I would change the height of an `OutlineButton`? I suppose this would likely apply to other button types as well.

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Test'),
    actions: <Widget> [
      SizedBox(
        width: 100.0,
        height: 8.0,
        child: OutlineButton(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 4.0)
          child: Text('Hi'),
          onPressed: (){},
        ),
      ),
    ],
   ),
  body: Container(),
);
```

I am finding the button just about 8px too high for my case, and want to squish it a bit.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[SizedBox](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) should do the work. Wrap your button by a SizedBox.

From the document:

> If given a child, this widget forces its child to have a specific width and/or height (assuming values are permitted by this widget's parent). If either the width or height is null, this widget will size itself to match the child's size in that dimension.
>   If not given a child, this widget will size itself to the given width and height, treating nulls as zero.

This will work for RaisedButton also

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Layout',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("SizedBox Demo"),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new SizedBox(
          width: 200.0,
          height: 80.0,
          child: new OutlineButton(
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 4.0),
              child: Text('I am a button'),
              onPressed: (() {})),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATED (2018/05/26):**

If you want to reduce the height of OutlineButton inside AppBar, use Padding

```dart
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Test'),
    actions: <Widget> [
      Padding(
        child: OutlineButton(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 4.0)
          child: Text('Hi'),
          onPressed: (){},
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    ],
   ),
  body: Container(),
);
```

Comment: This allows me to adjust the width, but for some reason, the height isn't changing.

Comment: updated the code. I guess the problem is because it's in the `AppBar` maybe. I didn't think that would affect it but it looks like it did. It locks the height.

Comment: Updated my answer for AppBar also. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

**Flutter 2.5**

OutlineButton is deprecated. Instead, use the Material button.
Put the Material Button inside Padding.
The padding property of Padding will control the height and width of the button.

```
AppBar(
        title: Text("Stack Overflow"),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              onPressed: () {

              },
              child: Text('SUBMIT'),
            ),
          )
        ],
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @phuc-tran, I've made a small fix:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Test'),
    actions: <Widget> [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: OutlineButton(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
          child: Text('Hi'),
          onPressed: (){},
        ),
      ),
    ],
   ),
  body: Container(),
);
```